# There exists no ideal $I$ such that $M^2 \subset I\subset M$ for $M$ a principal maximal ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I am looking for an answer to the question

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and let $M = (m)$ be a principal maximal ideal. Prove that there is no ideal $I$ such that $M^2 \subset I \subset M$.

I was given the following proof using module theory:

> The quotient $\overline{M} = M/M^2$ is a module over the field $K = R/M$. Moreover, it is one-dimensional because $M$ is principal. Therefore the only submodules are $0$ and $\overline{M}$. Lifting back to $R$, this shows that the only ideals contained in $M$ and containing $M^2$ are $M$ and $M^2$.

**Is there a proof of this question without appealing to module theory?**

I understand that $M^2 = (m^2)$, and it "makes sense" that $R/M^2$ is a local ring with its unique maximal ideal as $(m + M^2)$ since all elements have the form $a + bm + M^2$, but I'm having difficulty proving this.

Comment: Suppose $I$ contained $rm$, with $r\not\in M$. Then we can write $1=rt+sm$ for some $s,t$. Can you finish, assuming $I$ contains $m^2$?

Comment: @SteveD Oh, I see. Since $M$ is maximal, the ideal $(m,r)$ is all of $R$, so there exist $s,t\in R$ such that $rt + sm = 1$, and thus $m = t(rm) + s(m^2)$, which is in $I$. Thus $m\in I$, so $I = (m)$.

Comment: Please one of you consider posting a solution (or hint-solution, as it may be the case)

Comment: @SteveD If you wanted to submit that as an answer, I would gladly +1 and accept it.

Comment: The proof you gave is the **right** one; but of course you can rewrite it to disguise the use of vector space theory.

Comment: I strongly agree with Lord Shark here. Note also that the proof you give is about modules over a field, i.e., vector spaces: are you learning ring theory before linear algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $I$ contained $rm$, with $r\not\in M$. Since $M$ is maximal, we can write $1=rt+sm$ for $r,s\in R$. If we further assume $m^2\in I$, then we have $m=(rm)t+s(m^2)\in I$, and so $M\leq I$.

Thus if $M^2\le I\le M$, either $I=M$, or no such element $rm$ exists in $I$, and $I=M^2$.

Answer (score 4):

The proof “with elements” is the same as the proof “with vector spaces”: it's just a question of translation.

The module $M/M^2$ is a one dimensional vector space over $R/M$.

**Translation.** $M=(m)$.

If $I$ is an ideal between $M^2$ and $M$, $I\ne M^2$, then $I/M^2$ is a nonzero vector subspace of the one-dimensional space $M/M^2$, so it is the same as $M/M^2$.

**Translation.** Let $x\in I$, $x\notin M^2$. Then $x=rm$, for some $r\in R$, because $M=(m)$; since $x\notin M^2$, we have $rm\notin M^2$, in particular $r\notin M$; then $r+M$ is invertible in $R/M$, which means there are $s\in R$ and $y\in M$ with $1=rs+y$. Thus
$$
m=1m=(rs+y)m=s(rm)+ym\in I+M^2=I
$$
and therefore $I=M$.

Using vector spaces is just easier.